# How to repeatedly call a function for each iteration in a loop, get its results then append the results into a slice (Golang?

Tags: go

I have the ff:

```
func getSlice(distinctSymbols []string) []symbols {
    // Prepare connection
    stmt1, err := db.Prepare("Select count(*) from stockticker_daily where symbol = $1;")
    checkError(err)
    defer stmt1.Close()
    stmt2, err := db.Prepare("Select date from stockticker_daily where symbol = $1 order by date asc limit 1;")
    checkError(err)
    defer stmt2.Close()
    var symbolsSlice []symbols
    c := make(chan symbols)
    for _, symbol := range distinctSymbols {
        go worker(symbol, stmt1, stmt2, c)
        **symbolsFromChannel := <-c**
        **symbolsSlice = append(symbolsSlice, symbolsFromChannel})**
    }
    return symbolsSlice
}

func worker(symbol string, stmt1 *sql.Stmt, stmt2 *sql.Stmt, symbolsChan chan symbols) {
    var countdp int
    var earliestdate string
    row := stmt1.QueryRow(symbol)
    if err := row.Scan(&countdp); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    row = stmt2.QueryRow(symbol)
    if err := row.Scan(&earliestdate); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    symbolsChan <- symbols{symbol, countdp, earliestdate}
}
```

Please take a look at the first function, I know it won't work as I expect since the line `symbolsFromChannel := <-c` will block until it receives from the channel, so the iteration on the goroutine `go worker` will not continue unless the block is removed. What is the best or correct way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do the loop twice, e.g.

```
for _, symbol := range distinctSymbols {
        go worker(symbol, stmt1, stmt2, c)
}
for range distinctSymbols {
        symbolsSlice = append(symbolsSlice, <-c)
}
```

Comment: another problem occur, I don't know if I should put this in another thread. `2018/01/09 13:50:42 pq: remaining connection slots are reserved for non-replication superuser connections`